# Set up MySQL: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: python, mysql

I was trying to set up MySQL with Django.

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7 and 3.4 preinstalled (default is 3.4) and Django: 1.8.4.

I set it up following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)

1) Install sql and set admin password through the prompt window

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev
```

2) Create database directory

```
sudo mysql_install_db
```

3) Run through security script and said yes for all question except the one asked me for new password

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Then I tried to logging into an interactive session with the following command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

The problem came, it says

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I searched online for this, but couldn't find the same situation or possible solution.

It's my first time tring to set up database for web framework, any suggestions are welcome! I'll be super greatful it there is any easy-to-follow tutorial that could help me through this process!

Thanks in advance!

**Update**:

I solved this problem by referring to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost). But I have to add sudo while restarting mysql.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: Is there a prompt asking you for a password? Also for easy going and development I strongly recommend using SQLite as it doesn't require setting up a huge db-server but is only a single file (it's rather imperformant though, so it's not suited for production). Did you take a look at the official django tutorial, too?

Comment: if there is no password try it without the "-p"

Comment: also i suggest creating another user to work with that has less privileges to avoid mistakes, and of course adding a password for security

Comment: @ChristopherSchäpersThanks for your response. I'm looking at the official django tutorial right now, but it doesn't provide detaild instruction on how to set it for MySQL. I wanted to set up MySQL with Django for future development. Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @yaelalfasi I tried this earlier, it will result in a similar error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: Googling the error would give lots of information, like http://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost. Can you try it and see if it works? Also your question is mostly related to mysql, so please be specific about mysql(installation, version) instead of mentioning django etc that you haven't started to work on.

Comment: if there is really no password, your root user might not be defined in localhost. any chance you created it remotely ? the user/password combination is per ip